# How to calculate the profitability of an investment property, taking mortgage leveraging into account?

Tags: mortgage, real-estate

If you buy a property with cash, its fairly easy to make a calculation by totaling your profits over the lifetime of your investment against investing the same amount into an index fund. But how does one make a similar calculation for a property purchased with a mortgage? Let's say I'm buying a house for 1 million and I'm putting down 100k as my initial payment, with 4% interest for the remaining years. What would be the total profitability of the investment presuming a $4000 monthly rental payment and a yearly increase of 3% in property prices?

Comment: You're ignoring taxes, repair (which can get **really** expensive), unoccupied time, and the time and expense to evict renters who stop paying and trash the place.

Comment: Anyway, "*buying a house for 1 million and I'm putting down 100k as my initial payment, with 4% interest for the remaining years*" means that there's an `N year` mortgage at 4%.  Any mortgage calculator will tell you the total interest paid.

Comment: @RonJohn what if I'm living in the property instead? I'm mainly interested in how to factor in the fact that the bank loans me money. Ignore the issue with renters for the sake of this question :)

Comment: @RonJohn sure, but the bank loans me 900k initially, which is a 10x leverage. How do I take this into account when calculating my profitability?

Comment: Your question confuses me, since you don't have that $900K in your pocket.  It (along with your $100K downpayment) went straight to the previous owner.  Or am I grossly misunderstanding you?

Comment: "I'm mainly interested in how to factor in the fact that the bank loans me money."  You pay interest on the mortgage.  4% on the outstanding balance.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @RonJohn correct, but I now own an asset which can bring profit in terms of rent (or saving on rent, if I live there) and appreciates in price. After I pay off the mortgage I can sell it.

Comment: You have a $1M asset and (initially a) $900K liability which you pay 4% interest on.  That's easy to calculate.

Comment: @RonJohn yes, but if I just invest that $100k into an index fund I won't have a 1m asset in the end.

Comment: "*but if I just invest that $100k into an index fund I won't have a 1m asset in the end*". You're ignoring the ongoing contributions to the index fund that didn't have to pay off the $900K mortgage.

Comment: @RonJohn these would be partially covered by saving on rent or having a renter, making the calculation more complex

Comment: Just based on what you give us, profitability is impossible to calculate, based on the factors mentioned in my first comment.  You've got to use a spreadsheet, enter in all the factors you can think of, and run different scenarios.

Comment: @JonathanReez You might want to look at a concept called "Cash on Cash" return. It provides a formula to figure out your profitability on an annual basis factoring in any borrowed money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with is to create a spreadsheet detailing one's total mortgage expenses and comparing them to investing into index funds instead. From my calculations real estate investment is profitable if you have a 30-year mortgage with a low downpayment, presuming that real estate prices grow at at least 1/3 of index funds growth rates.

Answer (score 2):

A decent rule of thumb for this is to take 50% of the rent proceeds and compare that against the obvious costs of ownership of the home P&I, taxes, insurance, and HOA for a person that has experience as a landlord.

With the numbers you describe, you will have a mortgage of 4,300 and have 2K in revenue.  You don't cite the other obvious costs, but if an experienced real estate investor bought this hypothetical property, they should plan to lose 27,600 plus the cost of taxes, insurance, and HOA the first year.

If you're inexperienced a decent rule of thumb is to plan on far less, and maybe zero revenue.  With such a plan it is easy for things to go better than expected.